# How can we stop showing short code in create or edit post section

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, shortcode

I've tried one solution which wasn't helpful i added js in admin area with css display none but problem is js takes few seconds to load and it's not good practice to show short code for few seconds. How can i prevent that thing.

Comment: Can you please explain in greater detail what it is you're asking?

Comment: @TonyDjukic i'm working on plugin forms customizable  and it's generating short code and it'll show on dashboard user plugin dashboard it'll be on user how they'll use through gutenberg or do_shortcode directly into html but i have not designed gutenberg styling yet and i wanna hide short code from gutenberg as long as i'll not add that functions for that i hope it'll help to understand...